# Possibility of assumption in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Can I make assumptions on the casted int value of system enums in C#?

For example:

```
//DayOfWeek
(int)DayOfWeek.Monday == 1,
(int)DayOfWeek.Tuesday == 2,
(int)DayOfWeek.Wednesday == 3,
(int)DayOfWeek.Thursday == 4,
(int)DayOfWeek.Friday == 5,
(int)DayOfWeek.Saturday == 6,
(int)DayOfWeek.Sunday == 0
```

The logic of my code depends on it. However, I don't feel like writing my own mapping, because it... is just a wrong solution.

**EDIT**
Also here comes the culture thing as well. The ISO standard - Monday the 1st day. In USA - Sunday the 1st day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on it, insofar as it is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that:

> The DayOfWeek enumeration represents the day of the week in calendars
>   that have seven days per week. The value of the constants in this
>   enumeration ranges from DayOfWeek.Sunday to DayOfWeek.Saturday. If
>   cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates
>   DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).

Of course, while it is very unlikely that they would do so, Microsoft is free to change this in future releases.

Comment: Microsoft is highly unlikely to change this in future releases, given that A) doing so will probably break a lot of code, B) The current behavior is documented.  It is explicitly permissible to rely on documented behavior.

Comment: @Brian good point, I edited to clarify that. Microsoft is pretty good about backwards compatibility as well.

Comment: Is there any reason you felt it necessary to call out that Microsoft might someday change their definition of this enumeration? That is, why would you even mention the possibility of a behavior change (but not mention it in every other answer to any other question)?

Comment: @Brian Mostly because the questions was "Can I make this assumption?" to which the answer is "right now, and probably in the future". Most questions aren't asking if an assumptions is/will be valid.

Comment: @Brian: Because their current definition does not conform to the ISO 8601 standard, so it would have been a suitable candidate for change, were it not for the issue of backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is default enumeration (as linked in BradleyDotNET [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29173637/477420)) you can rely on the fact that values will be sequential and stay the way they are documented (also it generally good idea not to rely on particular values of numerations).

To get first day of the week you should you [DateTimeFormatInfo.FirstDayOfTheWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.firstdayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

So if your actual goal is to have list of 1st-7th day of the week mapped to `DayOfWeek.Monday` you need to use `CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat` to get formatting info and than map numbers you need according to `FirstDayOfTheWeek` property. Basic +/% math should work fine to compute day.

Something like (untested):

```
dayToEnumMap[1] = (DayOfWeek)(((int)(DayOfWeek.Sunday) +
    (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfTheWeek)) 
     % 7)
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers assigned to enum values are culture independent. Below you can take a look at the way it's [defined in the .Net framework](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/dayofweek.cs,fe3a0e5f847fa6f8):

```
[Serializable]
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
public enum DayOfWeek {
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6,
}
```

So Sunday is always equal to 0, Monday to 1 and so on.